# List filtering error when i match a row name "StaleDataException"

Tags: android, listview, staledataexception

Hi guys I'm getting an error, StaleDataException. This error keeps occurring if the edit text i am using to filter the list is blank or it matches a "Like Criteria". Im using a cursor to try and fetch the new rows, any help for this would be great as I haven't got an answer yet?

```
 public class CBFilter extends ListActivity {

EditText Filter;
ListView RecipeNames;
Cursor cursor, c;
CBListAdapter adapter;
CBDataBaseHelper data, data2;
//SQLiteDatabase data2;
TextView RecipeText, RowId;
String[] from = { CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME};
int[] to = { R.id.rowText};
ImageView image;
byte[] dataImage;
BufferedInputStream buf;
public static final String TAG = "Error";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

//FileInputStream in;//= openFileInput("//STEFAN-PC/Users/stefan/Desktop/Uni Work/Image.jpg");
RecipeNames = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
RecipeNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
RecipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
Filter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);

//adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, 0, cursor, null, null);
//image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RecipeImage);
data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);
data.open();
cursor = data.query();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter = new CBListAdapter(this, 0, cursor, from, to);
RecipeNames.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
    CBListAdapter filteradapter = (CBListAdapter)RecipeNames.getAdapter();
    filteradapter.setFilterQueryProvider(filterQueryProvider);

    //RecipeNames.setAdapter(filteradapter);

    filteradapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    filteradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "sumthing wrong", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }




});
}



public void CreateNew(View view){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
    String s = String.valueOf(rowId);
    intent1.putExtra("SELECTED", s);
    startActivity(intent1);
}


 public FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence _constraint) {
           // CBDataBaseHelper dh2;
            data.open();
            Cursor c = data.filter(_constraint);
            startManagingCursor(c);

            Cursor cur = data.query();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty((_constraint ))){

            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
           return cur ;


            }
            cur.close();
          }

            return c;
          }



    };
            // data2.open();
             //return data2.filter(_constraint);




}
```